# Difference between .string and db in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

I have to declare a string in assembly.

What is the difference between .string and db for declaring string?

Comment: I fear the semantics of these types of directives differ heavily between assembler dialects. As far as I can tell neither MASM, nor NASM, nor GAS has both of these. Which assembler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

db literally places that byte right there in the executable

Comment: Do you mean that .string <string> places the string on heap but db <string> places the string on the stack ?

Comment: String Allocate space and put characters in it. db defines a byte. That's different.